# Matlab: creating a (non-constant) tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Because it is possible to create a (non-constant) diagonal matrix in Matlab, f.i. `A = diag([1;2;3])`, I wonder if there is an easy way to create a non-constant tridiagonal matrix. Because the gallery('tridiag',...) command is only working with constant tridiagonal matrices.

Comment: Look up `spdiags`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html - If desired, convert the matrix to `full` as this produces a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then you can create *random* tridiagonal matrices using the below line of code

```
n=10; 
p=3;
T=toeplitz([1 randn(1,n-p-1) zeros(1,p)], [1 randn(1,n-p-1) zeros(1,p)])*diag(randn(1,n))
```

Note, you can also change the `1` in the toeplitz function or you can remove it all along, but then you get a warning.